# Twig infinite loop when rendering templates that have a Symfony Form in them. (Symfony 5.4)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to upgrade a legacy PHP application from PHP 7.2 and Symfony 3.4 to currently supported versions (8.2 / 5.4 respectively), and am running into an infinite loop when rendering certain twig templates that have a form in them.

When I try to load a page with a form, I get an OOM error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError: "Error: Out of memory (allocated 3509583872) (tried to allocate 90112 bytes)" at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php line 432 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\OutOfMemoryError(code: 0): Error: Out of memory (allocated 3509583872) (tried to allocate 90112 bytes) at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php:432)"}
```

In response, I enabled a profiler. That then gives this output when trying to load the same page:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '1024' frames" at /vendor/sylius/theme-bundle/src/Translation/Translator.php line 127 {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '1024' frames at /vendor/sylius/theme-bundle/src/Translation/Translator.php:127)"} []
```

Changing the stack depth has not had any impact on this profiler error.

One such page is to create a new System Property for the application, so I will use that as my example.

## SystemPropertyController.php

```
<?php

namespace UtilBundle\Form;

use ApiBundle\Entity\SystemProperty;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use UtilBundle\Form\SystemPropertyType;

public class SystemPropertyController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new SystemProperty entity.
     *
     * @Route("/systemProperty/new", name="systemProperty_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new SystemProperty();
        $form = $this->createForm(SystemPropertyType::class, $entity);

        return $this->renderForm("SystemProperty/new.html.twig", [
            'form'   => $form,
        ]);
    }
}
```

## SystemProperty.php

```
<?php

namespace ApiBundle\Entity;

class SystemProperty {
    
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    // public getters and setters for all fields removed below to save space in the post
}
```

## SystemPropertyType.php

```
<?php

namespace UtilBundle\Form;

use ApiBundle\Entity\SystemProperty;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SystemPropertyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) : void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name: *',
                'required' => true
                ])
            ->add('value', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Value: *',
                'required' => true
                ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description: *',
                'required' => true,
                'attr'   =>  [ 'rows' => 3 ]
                ])
        ;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => SystemProperty::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'system_property';
    }
}
```

## SystemProperty/new.html.twig

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="portlet box blue">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>Add New System Property
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body form">
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                    <div class="form-body">
                        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
                        <div id="msgCheckUnique" class="alert alert-danger fade in hidden">
                            <strong>Error!</strong> This name is already in use.<br />
                            Please try other one.<br/>
                        </div>
                        {{ form_row(form.value) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.description) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button class="btn blue" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        <button class="btn default" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1);">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Additional Info

- When I comment out the `form_start()`, `form__row()`, and `form_end()` lines in the twig template, the page loads just fine (without the form fields of course).
- Pages that do not have a form on them render without issue
- This problem is happening in an AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2
- This problem is NOT reproducible in Ubuntu 22

Comment: Have you tried disabling the translator? Maybe it got trapped in some cachy Symfony bootstrapping? No idea if stack depth of 1024 is just how Symfony does it, but in my book it's far too high already. And I would go in there with a step-debugger, when you port the app, you need to have (or I highly recommend that to you) the dev setup close to production already. In Phpstorm you can have a PHP webrequest run configuration with xdebug so it is easy(/easier) to replay & debug from the IDE already.